# What is wrong with my shell script in SunOS, runs fine on other linux flavours

Tags: linux, shell, csh, sunos

Please can someone identify what is the problem in my shell script, it works fine on other Linux systems except on Sunos below is my output

```
drifter% cat run.sh
#!/bin/sh -x
if [ ! $JAVA_HOME ] || [ $JAVA_HOME == "" ]
then
    echo Enter path to JAVA HOME:
    read JAVA_HOME
fi

if [ ! -f $JAVA_HOME/bin/java ]
then
echo "JAVA_HOME variable does not point to a valid java instance"
exit 1
fi

echo "Using JAVA_HOME: "$JAVA_HOME
JAVA_BIN=$JAVA_HOME/bin
ver=`$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version 2>&1 | head -1 | awk '{print $NF}' | cut -d'.' -f2`

if [ $ver -ge 5 ]
then
    JAVA_LIB=`pwd`/lib
    export JAVA_LIB

    $JAVA_BIN/java -cp ./lib/a-jdbc-sqlserver-4.2.1.jar:./lib/a-jdbc-db2-4.2.1.jar:./lib/ilmInit.jar:./lib/db2jcc.jar:./lib/db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar:./lib/db2jcc_license_cu.jar:./lib/csm-runtime-1.0.jar:./lib/csm-dbutil-1.0.jar:./lib/classes12_g.jar:./lib/commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar:./lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:./lib/commons-exec-1.1.jar:./lib/log4j-1.2.8.jar:./lib/groovy-all-1.8.1.jar -Dlog4j.configuration=com/a/csm/log4j.xml -Dendorsed_plugins_dir=./plugins InitValues $@

else
    echo Current JDK $ver
    echo "Expected JDK 1.5 or later. Please fix your JAVA HOME and try again."
    exit 1
fi
drifter% ./run.sh
+ [ ! ]
./run.sh: test: argument expected
drifter%
```

**Note**: I am using **`csh`**

**Update**

I changed `"$JAVA_HOME"` everywhere

but still i get

```
drifter% ./run.sh
+ [ ! /home/ilma1/java16/java ]
+ [ /home/ilma1/java16/java ==  ]
./run.sh: test: unknown operator ==
```

Comment: Also: I'd use `-x` to test for `java` instead of `-f`, to make sure it's executable.

Comment: Interesting: "SunOS" and "other Linux flavours". Since when is SunOS a Linux?

Comment: @glglgl: hmm i din knew that. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably `$JAVA_HOME` isn't set.  An unset variable normally expands to an empty string, so this:

```
if [ ! $JAVA_HOME ] || [ $JAVA_HOME == "" ]
```

is equivalent to this:

```
if [ ! ] || [ == "" ]
```

which is a syntax error.  (`[` is another name for the `test` command; it's usually a symbolic link.)

Try quoting the variable name:

```
if [ "$JAVA_HOME" == "" ]
```

And if you set `$JAVA_HOME` in response to the prompt, you probably want to `export` it.  (Actually I'm not sure of that; does `java` depend on `$JAVA_HOME` being set?)

**EDIT**:

Ok, it looks like `$JAVA_HOME` was set.

For the `test` (or `[`) command, the string equality operator is `=`, not `==`.

Try:

```
if [ "$JAVA_HOME" = "" ]
```

**EDIT2**:

This:

```
if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ]
```

is probably better (see @n.m's answer).

Comment: The `java` executable *itself* does **not** usually depend on (or read) `$JAVA_HOME`. However, it is pretty common for third-party applications that run on Java to evaluate that variable to find out *which `javac`* they should execute (Tomcat is a common example).

Comment: @Keith: Please check my updated question, even after i used `"$JAVA_HOME"` everywhere and set `JAVA_HOME` to a valid path i get some error, please refer my update. Yes in this case Java depends $JAVA_HOME

Comment: `=` works so what is the difference between `=` and `==` here?

Comment: @AbhishekSimon: As you observe, `=` works.  `==` is a syntax error.

Comment: @Keith: Thanks so in linux `=` is string equality opertor ;)

Comment: @AbhishekSimon: First, [SunOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunos) is *not* [Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) (please follow the links).  Second, `=` is the string equality operator *for the `test` (`[`) command; it may be something else in other contexts.  The bash shell has `test` and `[` as a built-in command, and it permits `==` as a synonym for `=` -- but as you've seen, `=` is more portable (and is specified by the POSIX standard).

Answer (score 1):

The portable way to check for empty strings is

```
if [ -n "%VAR" ]  #true if $VAR is non-empty
```

or

```
if [ -z "$VAR" ]  # true if $VAR is empty
```

It is also possible to use `if [ "x$VAR" == "x" ]`. This form is useful to compare arbitrary string that could be empty, e.g. `if [ "x$JAVA_HOME" == "x$SCALA_HOME" ]`.

Th form `if [ "$VAR" ]` can fail with some older incarnations of shell, though modern SunOS should be OK.

Comment: Is this what you meant me to do? `if [ ! "$JAVA_HOME" ] || [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ]`

Comment: The two halves of `||` do the same thing. Just one with `-z` should be enough.

Comment: `=` is more portable that `==`.  I've seen `if [ "x$VAR" = "X" ]`; when would that work and `if [ "$VAR" = "" ]` not work?  Just very old systems?

Answer (score 0):

== is not an operator in sh.  A single = is the posix compliant test operator.

```
if [ ! $JAVA_HOME ] || [ $JAVA_HOME = "" ]
```

I have just had this problem on Solaris 10, and found a great snipped of information in this ten year old post:
http://lists.infowares.com/archive/clug/2003-February/001849.html

> I just tried 'if [ "a" == "a" ]; then echo yes; fi' at the bourne
>   shell prompt on several different platforms. Solaris said 'test:
>   unknown operator ==' AIX said 'sh: ==: unknown test operator' HP-UX
>   said 'sh:==: A test command parameter is not valid.'   IRIX said 'yes'
>   (just to be different :) )

Secondly,
it's possible that sh doesn't know what to do with your empty string.  An old-school hack is to change your test to

```
[ XX"$JAVA_HOME" = XX"" ]
```

which for me compares [ XX/opt/jdk1.7.0_02 = XX ] which is false, rather than doing a test with an empty right hand side which fails in some shells.